Botframework webchat - Latex formatting
I would like to print in botframework webchat calculations using Latex formulas.
I know it support markdown however I wasn't able to find Latex support.
Does someone know how to implement this?
I have found MathJax lib but including into html script doesn't render the dynamic messages coming back from chatbot.

Botframewokr uses Markdown-it. Try to find a latex plugin
